# iOS Apps: Windows development & deployment - off-topic? How do I fix it without comments?

Tags: discussion, scope

Consider:

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559249/ways-to-sign-resign-certify-deploy-apps-to-iphone-5-ios-9-3-using-a-pc-witho*

I can rename it: How can I sign, resign, certify and deploy applications to an iPhone on a PC without needing a Mac OS X VM?

There are plenty of questions around the same, but missing this "niche question".

#### Development on Windows or without Mac/ Mac OS X

- *[How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)*
- *[iOS development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595507/ios-development-on-windows)*
- *[Alternatives For iOS Development Under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533847/alternatives-for-ios-development-under-windows)*
- *[Developing iOS app on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771361/developing-ios-app-on-windows)*
- *[iOS Emulator for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829896/ios-emulator-for-windows)*
- *[Xcode on windows for ios development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637879/xcode-on-windows-for-ios-development)*
- *[IOS programming on Windows system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410210/ios-programming-on-windows-system)*

#### Deployment

- *[iOS App deployment without AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301361/ios-app-deployment-without-appstore)*
- *[IOS Deployment with Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076886/ios-deployment-with-ionic)*
- *[Deploying an iOS Application Using Apple Enterprise Developer Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261255/deploying-an-ios-application-using-apple-enterprise-developer-program)*
- *[Deploy and test application on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369191/deploy-and-test-application-on-device)*
- *[is there any way to distribute ios applications outside app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383881/is-there-any-way-to-distribute-ios-applications-outside-app-store)*
- *[iOS: Deploy and run app on device through command-line without jailbreaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579097/ios-deploy-and-run-app-on-device-through-command-line-without-jailbreaking)*
- *[Deploy an iphone app from xcode to iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091883/deploy-an-iphone-app-from-xcode-to-iphone)*
- *[How to deploy iOS app to a iPhone using Delphi Seattle without Apple developer account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663131/how-to-deploy-ios-app-to-a-iphone-using-delphi-seattle-without-apple-developer-a)*
- *[How to deploy Cordova app via CLI to a specified iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238668/how-to-deploy-cordova-app-via-cli-to-a-specified-iphone-device)*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195934/is-it-possible-to-deploy-apps-on-an-iphone-ipad-from-the-command-line?rq=1*
- *[Is it possible to give an iPhone App Development Course without Mac computers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855922/is-it-possible-to-give-an-iphone-app-development-course-without-mac-computers?rq=1)*
- *[Deploy to iPhone without running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013053/deploy-to-iphone-without-running?rq=1)*
- *[Working method to deploy iPhone app on jailbroken device without developer ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345605/working-method-to-deploy-iphone-app-on-jailbroken-device-without-developer-id?rq=1)*
- *[Signing and submitting app without Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514982/signing-and-submitting-app-without-mac?rq=1)*
- *[best way to deploy iPhone app to the end user without submitting to the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577813/best-way-to-deploy-iphone-app-to-the-end-user-without-submitting-to-the-app-stor?rq=1)*
- *[Can we deploy an app on iPhone without having paid account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296245/can-we-deploy-an-app-on-iphone-without-having-paid-account?rq=1)*

Comment: Wow! How did someone give a negative or downvote even before the posted Question appeared before me, right after I composed it. ?

Answer (score 7):

There's no editing that could improve [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559249/ways-to-sign-resign-certify-deploy-apps-to-iphone-5-ios-9-3-using-a-pc-witho). It's been closed for a valid reason, since you're asking us if there is a tool or website (off-site resource) which can sign/deploy apps.

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Based on all the links you provided on meta, you appear to wonder why those other questions haven't been closed, yet your question was closed.

- Some questions may be asking about (a problem with) a specific tool. You're asking us to recommend a tool.  There's a difference.
- Some types of questions were permitted in the past, but are no longer on-topic.

Just because other open questions exist which may not have been closed (either due to historical reasons, or because no one has gotten around to closing them), don't use their existence as a guide or justification for what should be permitted under the current [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) guidelines.

*By the way, if you carefully check those questions you provided, you'll see that at [least](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829896/ios-emulator-for-windows) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771361/developing-ios-app-on-windows)  actually have been closed.  You should take notice of all the yellow banners on the linked questions, that show that off-topic, too-broad, and dupe questions do get closed.*